# Calculation of tokens

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask

I'm new to smart contracts and still learning some solidity basics. The contract I created, should give the sender custom tokens for Ether.
I have trouble in calculating tokens and also decrease the token amount.

Here are my initial values

```
   uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
   uint256 _totalSupply = 1000000;
   uint128 constant RATE = 2;
```

For example, if I pay **1 ETH** I should get **2 Tokens.**

For some reason, it doesn't work here properly:

When I pay 1 Ether to this contract, I'm getting **2000 tokens** but instead, it should be **2 tokens**

```
uint256 tokens = msg.value * RATE;
```

Here is also something weird, I'm getting this value for `balances[owner]` and `_totalSupply`
**115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039455.584**

```
balances[owner] = balances[owner] - tokens;  
_totalSupply = _totalSupply - tokens;
```

here the function:

```
 function createTokens() payable
 {
    require(msg.value > 0);


    uint256 tokens = msg.value * RATE;  
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + tokens; //add tokens to senders balance
    balances[owner] = balances[owner] - tokens;           //subtract tokens from owners balance

    owner.transfer(msg.value);                            // transfer amount of ether to cotract owner
    Transfer(owner, msg.sender, tokens);                  // Broadcast a message to the blockchain

   _totalSupply = _totalSupply - tokens ;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `_totalSupply` is far too low. Remember that you have 18 decimal places, so 1 token is 1000000000000000000 (a 1 with 18 zeros after it). If you want to start with 1,000,000 tokens, you need to set _initialSupply to a 1 with 24 zeros after it (18 + 6).

Assuming you assign all the tokens to the `owner` upon initialization, both balances are suffering from an integer overflow after you subtract more tokens than exist. You should consider something like `require(_totalSupply >= tokens && balances[owner] >= tokens)` to guard against this.

As to why you're getting 2000 tokens instead of 2, I can't really say. Ether itself and your token both appear to use 18 decimal places. If you can share the full source code (and perhaps a link to where it's deployed, if it's deployed somewhere public), I might be able to help more.

Comment: Ohh I really missed the part with the decimals.... Thank you very much, so when I'm declaring decimals all values are based on it ? for example if the sender sends 2 Ether then the msg.value = 2 * 10^18 ?  do I need to then calc (msg.value * RATE)/10^18 ?

Comment: Yes, the `msg.value` is 2 * 10^18, and no, you don't want to divide that away. (Because you want to award 4 * 10^18 in your token. This will be 4 tokens.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try this conversion tool: https://ico.atorresg.com/